# AutoHotKey script fails after first use

Tags: autohotkey

I am working with a Help file as a Word 2007 document.  I need to update the screenshots as I go through, so I'm trying to get AHK to select the 'Change Picture' option from the right click drop down menu when I press my key combination.  I've got the code, and it works perfectly... the first time I use it.  After that, I only see the right click menu flash and disappear.  I suspect that the script from `Send {Down 4}` on is not executing because I can just barely see the 'Cut' option highlighted, but the selected image is not cut from the document, indicating that the `Send {Enter}` is also not being executed.

I cannot find anyone else who seems to be having this problem.  If I manually reload my script, it works fine again, but only the once.  Then it's back to flashing the drop down and nothing else.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm trying to get this process down to as few clicks as possible, but it's getting to the point where I'm wasting more time trying to solve my macro problems than I would just doing it the slow awkward way.

My script as it is now:

```
^!z::
    Send +{F10}
    Send {Down 4}
    Send {Enter}
    return
```

For clarification's sake:

When I remove everything following `Send +{F10}` and then use my hotkey, I get the right click menu displayed and not flashed, but again, only the first time I use it.  After that, the menu goes back to flashing on the screen once.  To compare, actually pressing Shift and {F10} displays the right click menu, and it does not disappear on lift.

If I move all three Send commands into one line to get `Send +{F10} {Down 4} {Enter}` The script executes the 'Cut' option from the right click menu, then moves the cursor down 4 lines and then sends the `{Enter}` keystroke.  This set of actions works after the first use of the script, unlike previous instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my copy of Word, the control key causes a secondary 'Layout Options' menu to pop up if there is an image selected.  While I'm not sure why it's working for you the first time but not subsequently, when I test this at my end it works if I change two things:

1. Use `mouseclick, right` instead of `Send +{F10}`
2. Change the shortcut modifier from shift-ctrl to Win, i.e. set it to `#z`

Comment: Your method works.  If nobody answers the question of why my original script doesn't work by the end of the day, I'll mark this as my accepted answer.  Thanks for your input.

As a side note:  removing ctrl from my original hotkey so that it's only alt+z doesn't execute the `mouseclick, right` command but does the other two.  I'm still pretty new to using AHK scripts, so this is both interesting and mysterious to me.

Comment: An... when the keystrokes are going too fast add a few lines with a small pause: `Sleep, 50` before executing the next instruction. This way the menu can keep up with the rapid fire from the script.

Comment: The problem is not in the speed at which the commands are sent to Word, it's in the fact that the script doesn't execute correctly after the first use.  It works fine the first time.  But if I select another picture and try again, no good.

Comment: I believe the context menu may cause odd interactions with the control keys being held down.  AFAIK, by the end of the script, the Control Keys are still held down (because the script is done very quickly), but the computer may think they're released.  It may also have brought up unintentional menus, or the Word application may have lost focus.  How do you get the hotkey to work again?  Reloading the script?  Restarting Word?

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the keyboard shortcut instead of down command

```
SetBatchLines, 1
SetKeyDelay , 100   ; in miliseconds, keep increasing until your pc can hadle it

!x::    ; your hotkey in my case alt + x which is similar to ctrl + x for cutting text
    Send +{F10}
    Send {t}    ; use the cut keyboard shortcut, for word should be 't'. if for some weird reason isn't change it
    Send {Enter}
return
```